# SQL to Classify items based on Parent status

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012

Find the *DDL,DML, Sample data*, What i have tried with actual output in [**Fiddle Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=252610a5802d5c2bc6cf82d87b8f3b6f) .

I have a table `Categories`. *I'm providing pictures below as the fiddle contains data in text format.Let me know if you want to replace the pics below with text data*

[image]

Also another table `CategoryRelation`

[image]

Now i'm trying to add another column in `Categories` called `Decision` and the expected output looks like below.

Expected Output

```
+------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
| CategoryID | Name             | Status   | Decision      |
+------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
| 1          | Electronics      | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 2          | Furnitures       | InActive | NOT-IN-USE    |
| 3          | Men's Clothing   | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 4          | Women's Clothing | InActive | NOT-IN-USE    |
| 5          | Jeans Pent       | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 6          | T-Shirts         | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 7          | Sarees           | Active   | NOT-IN-USE    |
| 8          | Shirts           | InActive | IN-USE        |
| 9          | Mobiles          | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 10         | TVs              | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 11         | Smartphone       | Active   | IN-USE        |
| 12         | Tables           | InActive | NOT-IN-USE    |
| 13         | Chairs           | InActive | NOT-IN-USE    |
| 14         | Stationaries     | InActive | TO_BE_DECIDED |
+------------+------------------+----------+---------------+
```

Logic:

1. Take all the categories with `Active` status and put `IN-USE` for all its children irrespective of its current status
2. Take all the categories with `InActive` status and put `NOT-IN-USE` for all its children only when all the children comes under `InActive` Parent items. If any of its children corresponds to one or more Active items, that child should be `Active`. For eg., Shirts in my sample data.
3. If any of the categories doesn't have any children, then it should be `TO_BE_DECIDED` irrespective of its current status. E.g `Stationaries`

I have almost done it but i dont know if that is right way or not. Also I have issues with `Sarees` which should be `NOT-IN-USE` but it is coming other way. Also not sure how to check for no child (`Stationaries`). Can somebody please help here?

Comment: Sounds like a `CASE` expression would do what you want

Comment: Are `ParentCategoryID` and `ChildCategoryID` text or numeric? Your example show them as text.

Comment: Those are `text` only. Actually those are names.`ParentCategoryName` and `ChildCategoryName` @TheImpaler. I forgot to rename it. Sorry about that

Comment: Before continuing to solve this problem y recommend you to think why you have that desing in your database, it doesn't look right. Bad database design can lead to major problems in the future.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by bad design here? @JoaquinAlvarez can u please elaborate it. It is just 2 table. One table with product details and other about its relationship.